# Не могу настроить routing MVC

Tags: php, mvc

Всем привет. Пытаюсь создать простую MVC . C Controller и Model нет проблем, что не могу сказать с routing. Перелопатил кучу материала - но собрать в кучу не могу. Нужно очень простым способом при переходе '/action' выполнить Controller@action

index.php

```
$obj = new ParseUrl();
$obj->run();
```

ParseUrl

```
class ParseUrl
{
    public function getRoute()
    {
        $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        return $uri;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        return $this->getRoute();
    }
}
```

Путь я получаю (при вводе http://localhost/address  возвращает строку address)но куда дальше?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цель роутера, не получить урл который ввел пользователь (т.к. его можно получить просто из $_SERVER или $_REQUEST), а в том что бы его разобрать.
т.е.:
- получаем урл что ввел пользователь.
- разделяем на контроллер и екшен.
- проверяем есть ли у нас такой контроллер, если нет, то запускаем дефолтный типа для 404.
- если такой есть, отдаем

```
public function getRoute()
    {
        $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        return array_pop(explode('/', $uri));
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $action = $this->getRoute();
        $controller = lcfirst($action . 'Controller');
        if(file_exists(__DIR__.'/Controller/'.$controller.'.php')){
            require_once(__DIR__.'/Controller/'.$controller.'.php');
        }
        $action = 'indexAction';
        return call_user_func_array(array($controller, $action), []);
    }
```

и в папке Controller создаем AddressController

```
class AddressController {

    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo "Address Controller";
    }

}
```

**P.S. это крайне примитивный и простейший пример как вызвать контроллер и класс.**